# Converting vertical menu to horizontal menu

Tags: css

I have a vertical menu which I want to make horizontal. I have tried placing display:inline tag but it does not do the job. Please guide. Thanks.

```
#access div {
    margin: 0;
    width:140px;
}
#access {
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    float: left;
}
#access ul {
    font-size: 11px;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#access li {
    line-height: normal;
    position: relative;
    display:inline;
}
#access a {
    color: #B25326;
    display: block;
    padding: 4px 0;
    text-decoration: none; font-size: 10px;
    text-align:right; text-transform:uppercase;
    line-height: normal;
}
#access a:hover {
    color: #000000 !important;
}
#access ul ul {
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    box-shadow: 0 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    display: none;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 3.333em;
    left: 0;
    width: 188px;
    z-index: 99999;
}
#access ul ul ul {
    left: 100%;
    top: 0;
}
#access ul ul a {
    background: #f9f9f9;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #ddd;
    color: #444;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: normal;
    height: auto;
    line-height: 1.4em;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    width: 168px;
}
#access li:hover > a,
#access ul ul :hover > a,
#access a:focus {
    background: none;
}
#access li:hover > a,
#access a:focus {
    color: #000000;
}
#access ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}
#access .current-menu-item > a,
#access .current-menu-ancestor > a,
#access .current_page_item > a,
#access .current_page_ancestor > a {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: Your code is absolutely horrible, please look into properly formatting. Also, show the HTML.

Comment: We need the markup and a fiddle to be able to help you on that SIR!

Comment: We really need a JSfiddle to help you out. The general concept is to take each `li` and either use `float:left` or `display:inline / inline-block`

Comment: First thing to do is take the width off of the div...no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First take the width off from the div and then you can use:

```
#access li {
    float:left;    
}
```